# Looking for a classier word to describe a "packet" or "envelope"

Tags: word-choice

At work, we sent a packet (letter-sized envelope filled with letter-sized things) out to a bunch of different people who had reached certain sales goals in our company. They have a bit of pomp about them, so while calling it a 'packet' or 'kit' is accurate, it comes up a bit short in my mind.

Looked up synonyms...'sachet' was an interesting idea, but its definition didn't quite seem to fit and it feels a little TOO pretentious :)

Any other ideas?

Comment: Can these letter-sized things be generalized into a word or two?  I'm always tempted to use words referring to packs of animals.  "The correspondence swarm."  I am also fond of the word "mess" in relation to a collection of things (particularly if it isn't much of a mess at all).

Comment: Presumably the paper-sized thingies were good instead of bad, so one could simply call it an award (even better, the prestigious _[insert name here] Award_). Or a reward, or a bonus pak, or you might ask what the recipients call it and adopt their terminology; after all, they're the ones you want to pay attention to, no?

Answer (score 2):

You might consider **letters of recognition**, **commendation letters**, or simply **commendations**.

(I think you could get by with "letters of..." Even if the package contains more than a letter. )

Answer (score 1):

Here at Stackexchange, they called it *[swag](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1353/english-stack-exchange-swag-for-top-users)*.

Comment: "Swag" works as an I formal expression, but it brings to mind other (informal) words, like "booty", "treasure", and "goodie". Those words don't carry the formality implied by performing an honorific act.

Answer (score -1):

A very-slightly-better suggestion than *[sachet](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sachet#Noun)* (in its sense of “a small, sealed packet containing a single-use quantity of any material”) might be *[cachet](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cachet#Noun) sachet*, since *cachet* means “a special characteristic or quality”.  You refer to *sachet* as “too pretentious”, but having two  words that rhyme  replaces some of the pretentiousness by cuteness.

Comment: I don't see that _cachet_ has quite that meaning, but even if we accept that as being close to its meaning, _cachet_ is still a noun, so using it as an adjective is a bit off.